# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: react using axios and fastapi

Tags: reactjs, fastapi

i'm trying to send image from react to fastapi and i did all the configration of middleware in the backend and the axios configration but it gives me the error (Cross-Origin Request Blocked)

and this the function i'm using to upload the image it gives me network error

```
const sendFile = async () => {
if (image) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", selectedFile);
  let res = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
    data: formData,
    mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  credentials: 'same-origin',
});
```

and this my backend api i tested the backend with postman and it's work fine

```
origins = [

"http://localhost:3000",
"http://localhost/predict",
"http://localhost/ping",
"http://localhost:8080",
"http://localhost:8080/predict",
"http://localhost:8080/ping",
```

]

```
app.add_middleware(
CORSMiddleware,
allow_origins=origins,
allow_credentials=True,
allow_methods=["*"],
allow_headers=["*"],
expose_headers=["*"],
```

)

```
endpoint = "http://localhost:8502/v1/models/potatoes_model:predict"

CLASS_NAMES = ["Early Blight", "Late Blight", "Healthy"]

@app.get("/ping")
async def ping():
    return "Hello, I am alive"

def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
    file: UploadFile = File(...)
):



image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)

json_data = {
    "instances": img_batch.tolist()
}

response = requests.post(endpoint, json=json_data)

pass
prediction = np.array(response.json()["predictions"][0])

predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(prediction)]
confidence = np.max(prediction)

return {
    "class": predicted_class,
    "confidence": float(confidence)
}
```

finally this the error appears to me by firefox console
[The Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcE78.png)

Comment: Are you already familiar with CORS? If not I guess it's time to have look at it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. It seems there is a CORSMiddleware for FastAPI you could use https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/

Comment: i configured the middleware like the link above but it also not working

Comment: Did you understand what CORS is or did you just copy paste the middleware config from the website?

Comment: i just know the basics of cors like i need it when i need to access data in another domain and i saw many examples of cors in fastapi and axios and i did the same steps as in the examples also i was following a tutorial and i did the same thing but it also not work

Comment: this is the link of the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGtDTjYs3xc&t=43s

Comment: You do not have `http://localhost` as an origin in your list (the error message complains about `http://localhost` not being allowed as an origin address). Origins do _not_ have a path, so `/predict` etc. should _not_ be included. (You can't set CORS headers in your client fetch code either, but that shouldn't affect this negatively)